# javascript won´t work in Twitter´s Bootstrap, even when links to the proper css/js files are ok (I´m hotlinking to them)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve tested with several files, and decided to hotlink every single css and js file that I think is needed.

But still the javascript won´t work.

I´ve added 4 files of Twitter´s Bootstrap at: http://jsfiddle.net/PS3LH/
If I paste inside the css area the css required it seems to work, but the css file is already added, so I don´t know why it doesn´t work...

Thanks for your help!

Rosamunda

Comment: Have you checked to see if a javascript error is occurring?

Comment: I added a working example to my answer.

Comment: An error might help? Have you used firebug to see what javascript is struggling with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have JQuery loaded first, then tooltip, then popover.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLvUj/

Your bootstrap CSS had the wrong URL too.  Above is a working example.